# How to remove subdomain with express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a website built on Node/Express4 with two subdomains, `www.awesome.com` and `api.awesome.com`.

This is working fine.

I also have a staging site, running a separate Node instance, running at `staging.awesome.com`. What I'd like to achieve is have `foo.staging.awesome.com` route to `foo.awesome.com` early in the request lifecycle, so my staging site distinguishes between `www.` and `api.` in exactly the same way as my production site.

I've tried adding the following early in my app.js:

```
app.use('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var hostname = req.hostname;
  var newHostname = hostname.replace(/staging\./g, "");
  req.hostname = newHostname;

  console.log(newHostname);
  console.log(req.hostname);

  next();
});
```

`newHostname` is set exactly how I want, but it seems I can't just set the hostname on the request like that. The log shows `req.hostname` hasn't been changed.

So, my question is. Either how to I overwrite the hostname in the request, or how do I conditionally remove the last subdomain. Either works :)

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I need the exact same thing.